# xcode 5 auto layout - view stretches, but not the view's contents

Tags: xcode, autolayout

In Xcode 5 OSX, not ios, I have created a view and set auto layout constraints so that the view's sides stay a fixed distance from the frame. The view stretches correctly by dragging the window's corner while running, but the content of the view remains fixed in size. The content consists of a Bezier path. Shrinking can crop the content, and expanding provides lots of open space next to the unchanging content.

I also notice that changing the initial position in the small colored window of the Window in its Size Inspector does not change the position of the window on the screen when it's run. It appears in the same place it was left in the previous run. Size also remains the same. Then it can be moved and resized on the screen, and it will appear there in the next run.

How can I make the content shrink or swell along with the view and window?

How can I make the Window's Size Inspector control the initial position on the screen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JeremyP: thank you for your guidance.

Here's what works. If it's interesting, this code and my comments can be seen in cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com, 9/29/2014 8:35 PM, about success using Graham Cox’s outline. Including it all here would be lengthy and might cause confusion.

```
// scale the content to track the frame

{
NSBezierPath *path;
NSRect bounds;
CGFloat scaleX,scaleY;
}


   scaleX =NSWidth(bounds)/NSWidth([path bounds]);
   scaleY =NSHeight(bounds)/NSHeight([path bounds]);


   NSAffineTransform* tfm = [[NSAffineTransform alloc] init];
   [tfm scaleXBy:scaleX yBy:scaleY];
   NSBezierPath* temp  = [tfm transformBezierPath:path];

   //   [tfm concat];

   [temp stroke];
```

Answer (score 0):

You presumably do the drawing of the view's content in code. You can choose to do that however you want. If you want the drawing to somehow be altered by the view's aspect ratio, incorporate that logic into your code.

You could also set the view's `bounds` rect to be different from its `frame` rect. Once you set the bounds, they are no longer automatically kept in sync with the frame. As a consequence, the translation from bounds to frame will no longer be a 1-to-1 mapping. As you change the frame, and given that the bounds won't change to track that, the mapping will effectively scale the view's content.

Deciding what the bounds should be is up to you. You could, for example, set it to the unit rect (origin at (0, 0), size 1x1). Obviously, you'd then need to account for the coordinate system in your drawing code.

See the [View Programming Guide: View Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html).

As to the window size: you have set an autosave name for your window. The whole purpose of that is to save the window position and restore it the next time the window is shown. If you don't want that behavior, don't set (i.e. clear) the window's autosave name.

Comment: 1. Aspect ratio is not an issue and was not mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't been able to create newlines with two spaces and return. It just closes the window and I have to re-open it.

Comment: 1. I did not mention spect ratio. It is not an issue       2.Changing bounds failed to make content track frame size.                                      3. View Programming Guide helps to set up a view, but does not address tracking. Furthermore, it does not provide explicit examples of using Affine Transforms. References to method definitions are not sufficient for me.                           4. The autosave name is and always has been left blank.

Comment: Please see my response in cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com today, 9/29/2014 8:35 PM, about success using Graham Cox’s outline.

Comment: @jyrez If you have an answer, please could you put it on here for future reference by other people encountering the same issue.  (You are allowed to answer your own questions).